# wildfly custom authorization

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have authentication module that uses AnyCertVerifier:

```
<security-domain name="cms_client_cert" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.BaseCertLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="verifier" value="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.AnyCertVerifier"/>
                        <module-option name="securityDomain" value="cms_client_cert"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
                <jsse truststore-password="" truststore-url="file:/${jboss.server.config.dir}/mytruststore" client-auth="true"/>
            </security-domain>
```

And now i want to add authorization, i.e. bind some roles with users? How can i do it? What class should i extend/implement?

So that i could use `RolesAllowed` annotation.

P.S. I don't want to deal with roles files. I would like to do it manually in the code, getting the roles from db.